# Adding existing route to a new button on ActiveAdmin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

After so much searching  I finally found a way to add a new button to ActiveAdmin default template.
Following is my **User.rb** file where I am adding a new button

```
  action_item only: :show do
    link_to "Resend Email"
  end
```

Currently it's routing to show action when clicked. But I wanted to route it to `UserMailer#confirmation_instructions`

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users,controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations',sessions: 'users/sessions',confirmations: 'users/confirmations'}
end
```

**Usermailer.rb**

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    @system_email = SystemEmail.find_by(title: 'Email Verification')
    @subject =  @system_email.try(:subject).to_s
    @subject = "Email Verification" if @subject.blank?

    opts = {subject: @subject}
    @token = token
    devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
  end
```

How can I can route it to `UserMailer#confirmation_instructions` ?? This AI have done these things on normal MVC architecture. But this is really eating my head. Can somebody please tell how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something along these lines:

```
action_item only: :show do
  link_to(
    'Resend email',
    resend_email_admin_user_path(user_id: user.id),
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to resend it?' }
  )
end

member_action :resend_email do
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  UserMailer.confirmation_instructions(user, user.token, {})
  redirect_to admin_user_path(user), notice: 'confirmation is sent'
end
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it is processing `Admin::UsersController#resend_email`  selects users and ends up giving error `undefined method `token' for User`     @Andrey Deineko.

Comment: @user3576036 seriously? Man, it is a mockup, you should pass the correct arguments to `UserMailer.confirmation_instructions` - how should I suppose to know what they should be? :)

Comment: I later passed the same arguments which I have passed for `def confirmation_instruction(record, token, opts={})`. It didn't work. I think this is the closest solution. This is new for me really. Just tell how what more content should I add to the question, so that you'll know what should be the arguments.

Comment: @user3576036 post the error you have with this setup (when you pass correct arguments to `confirmation_instruction`)

Comment: undefined local variable or method `record' for #<Admin::UsersController

Comment: @user3576036 it means you are close. Just think of it. While being inside the `resend_email` action (the one I posted) what is what and what should be passed into `confirmation_instructions`? Is record supposed to be `user`? what is `token`? Did you write the `confirmation_instructions` yourself or you have copied from somewhere without knowing what it supposed to do?

Comment: I am working on a existing code left by the earlier developer. and I hate working on existing code. He is passing `def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})` in **UserMailer** and it is working. It sends email when for the first time user is created. And now I am trying to pass the same arguments to have a "resend the email" option.

Comment: @user3576036 look into database, there should some column in `users` table, called auth_token or token or authenticity_token or crap_token - this is what you should pass. So `UserMailer.confirmation_instructions(user, user.THE_COLUMN_YOU_WILL_FIND, {})
 `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137285/discussion-between-user3576036-and-andrey-deineko).